# При вставке в ttk.Treeview() добавляются пустые строки без переданных данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Есть читаемый из файла `ttk.Treeview()`. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на клавишу снималось значение со строки ввода и список в реальном времени пополнился введённым элементом. Написал что-то, но при нажатии на клавишу в `ttk.Treeview()` добавляется пустая строка, но не значение из `tkinter.Entry()`.

```
text = open('list_of_tasks.txt', 'a')
text.write(enter.get() + '\n')
text.close()
panel_of_tasks.insert('',tkinter.END, text =enter.get())
window_enter_task.destroy()
```

Comment: а как работа с файлом `text` относится к вопросу? Приведите в вопросе минимальный пример с ошибкой

Comment: Мне кажется , вы понимаете, что в  panel_of_tasks.insert('',tkinter.END, text =enter.get())  , text это параметр для передачи заголовка строки таблицы. Так вот , когда я выполняю этот кусок кода и всё остальное, у меня появляется пустая строка в ttk.Treeview() , но она не заполняется значением.

Answer (score 1):

`Treeview` может работать в нескольких режимах, настраивается через параметр `show`:

1. Дерево (`show="tree"`)
2. Таблица (`show="headings"`)
3. Дерево с таблицей (`show="tree headings"`) - по умолчанию.

При вставке через `insert` параметр `text` отвечает за название в колонке дерева, параметр `values` (список или кортеж) отвечает за вставку значений в колонки таблицы.

Документация: [Treeview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview)

Какие могут быть подводные камни, из-за которых при вставке в новой строке ничего не отображается:

1. Выбран режим таблицы с отключенным деревом (`show="headings"`), а вставка идет с передачей текста в `text` - т.к. дерево отключено, этот текст нигде не отобразится
2. Вставка через `values`, режим дерева с таблицей или просто таблицы, но не добавлена ни одна колонка через параметр `columns` при создании `Treeview`. Колонок нет, переданным через `values` данным негде отображаться.

---

Минимальный рабочий пример добавления строки из `Entry` с добавлением текста в колонку дерева `Treeview`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

enter = tk.Entry(root)
enter.pack()

panel_of_tasks = ttk.Treeview(root)


def add_line():
    panel_of_tasks.insert('', tk.END, text=enter.get())


ttk.Button(root, text="Add line", command=add_line).pack()

panel_of_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Если при создании `Treeview` указан параметр `show="headings"` (что отключает отображение дерева), то при вставке текста через параметр `text` будут добавляться просто пустые строки. В этом случае данные нужно передавать как кортеж через параметр `values`:

```
panel_of_tasks.insert('', tk.END, values=(enter.get(),))
```

При этом при создании `Treeview` нужно передать список или кортеж хотя бы с одним элементом в параметр `columns`, иначе колонок не будет, и данные из `values` в таблице не отобразятся (потому что негде отображать, колонок-то в таблице нет).

Полный пример:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

enter = tk.Entry(root)
enter.pack()

heading = 'Заголовок колонки'
panel_of_tasks = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=[heading], show="headings")
panel_of_tasks.heading('#1', text=heading)

def add_line():
    panel_of_tasks.insert('', tk.END, values=(enter.get(),))


ttk.Button(root, text="Add line", command=add_line).pack()

panel_of_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

В `columns` в принципе можно передавать не список с названиями колонок (эти названия ни на что не повлияют, названия колонок все равно нужно будет проставлять через метод `heading`), а список с идентификаторами колонок, по которым можно будет к ним обращаться, можно даже `list(range(N))`, где N - нужное количество колонок. Потом через метод `heading` менять заголовок:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

enter = tk.Entry(root)
enter.pack()

panel_of_tasks = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=list(range(1)), show="headings")
panel_of_tasks.heading(0, text='Заголовок колонки')

def add_line():
    panel_of_tasks.insert('', tk.END, values=(enter.get(),))


ttk.Button(root, text="Add line", command=add_line).pack()

panel_of_tasks.pack()

root.mainloop()
```